# Does WireMock accommodate correlation?

Tags: java, mocking, jetty, wiremock

Is there any concept of correlation in WireMock?

I want to transfer a value from a request into the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on it right now. Hope to release in the next couple of weeks (or early in the new year if festive demands prove to be too much).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will use the extension for now. Great work man.